# ReadTimeoutException Event

Tags: netty

I am using Netty IO version 3.6.3 and have a pipeline with upstream and downstream handlers. The server implemented reads a message, processes it, and sends a response. There is a ReadTimeoutHandler included as the first handler for the pipeline. If the processing exceeds the timeout the ReadTimeoutException event is fired. Sometimes it fires before the response is written on the channel. When the exceptionCaught() method responds to the ReadTimeoutException event the code adjusts the response with the timeout exception and attempt to write the response to the channel. However the channel is closed. It appears that the ReadTimeoutException generated by the ReadTimeoutHandler has automatically closed the channel. I presume the client has detected the the closing of the channel. The Javadoc does not describe this behavior. I would like to be able to write a response. I tried to reconnect the channel in the exceptionCaught() method but that fails.

Any suggestions or information on how to handle read timeouts where you would like a response to be sent back to the client?

Comment: I found out that the firing of the ReadTimeoutException is not the cause of the channel closing. In fact, the I/O Thread sent the response via "ChannelFuture future = channel.write(response)". The future has a ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE listener which closes the channel on completion. If the timing changes and the ReadTimeoutException fires before the response is sent the channel is still open in the caughtException() method. I hope this comment clarifies the process for others who also may be initially confused with ChannelPipelines and ChannelHandlers.